# Linux Pthreads User level or kernel level

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how are pthreads on linux seen by scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004662/how-are-pthreads-on-linux-seen-by-scheduler)

Are Linux pthreads user level threads or Kernel level threads ?

Answer (score 5):

The Linux kernel schedules threads rather than processes. As far as the scheduler is concerned, processes are now an *artificial* construct mostly for userland purposes.

When you create a *process,* it is a single thread where the thread ID (the kernel actually refers to this as a PID but that might be confusing so I'll refer to it as a TID here) and thread group ID (TGID) are identical.

If a thread creates a new thread (rather than a new process), it inherits the TGID from the creator, but gets a new TID.

In other words, the thread *group* can be considered the process, but the scheduler doesn't care - it works on individual threads.

So, in answer to your specific question, they're kernel-level threads.